# Responsive spacing in SVG group?

Tags: css, svg, responsive, responsive-images

I've got a SVG exported from Adobe XD, it is a collection of five "cards" showing some people's faces arranged in a particular pattern. Here is how the code is structured:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="700" height="430" viewBox="0 0 700 430">
  <defs>
  ...
  </defs>
  <g id="USERS" clip-path="url(#clip-USERS)">
    <g id="Group" transform="translate(-793.227 -295.708)">
      <g id="User_5" data-name="User 5" transform="translate(1340.921 326.103) rotate(-14)">
      ...
      </g>
      <g id="User_4" data-name="User 4" transform="translate(1052.907 570.449) rotate(16.024)">
      ...
      </g>
      <g id="User_3" data-name="User 3" transform="translate(1170.434 426.218) rotate(-14)">
      ...
      </g>
      <g id="User_2" data-name="User 2" transform="translate(984.139 426.348) rotate(-14)">
      ...
      </g>
      <g id="User_1" data-name="User 1" transform="translate(827.868 347.168) rotate(16.024)">
      ...
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

I need to place the image on a website which has a responsive background, and I am trying to make the size of the image responsive as well.

With Adobe XD, I can resize the group without changing the aspect ratio of the cards - that is, only the space between them is affected. I am trying to achieve the same with the SVG on my website.

Here is a GIF of what I'd like to obtain specifically:

[image: responsive resize]

So far, I've tried substituting `width="700" height="430"` with `width="100%" height="auto"` in the SVG header, maybe even adding `preserveAspectRatio="none"`, but that affects the entire image, not only the space between objects.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is not possible just by messing with `viewBox` and `preserveAspectRatio`.  Anything inside the SVG will be scaled along with the SVG itself.

You would need to use Javascript, then either:

- Don't use `viewBox` and instead reposition the cards yourself according to the current width and height, or
- Let SVG reposition and scale them (using `viewBox` etc) , and then apply the inverse scaling transform to each card to counteract the scaling that SVG applied.

Alternatively, make each card a separate SVG image and use CSS to position them relative to the parent width and height.

Comment: I originally avoided the manual positioning option, but I will probably go for that. Thanks!